# Crontab not working fine

Tags: unix, cron

I have the below script (/support/memexsvr_count) which is used for the no. of current users logged in the application.

When i run manually the output is different as it run through crontab. 
Can anyone advise me asap.

crontab

```
#Count
* * * * * /support/memexsvr_count.sh
```

Script

```
x=`(date)`
y=`(ps -ef|grep memexsvr|wc -l)`
z=`expr $y - 3`
echo "Number of memexsvr processes at $x is $z" >> /support/memexsvr_count.log
```

Manual run : output

```
Number of memexsvr processes at Tuesday, 10 September 2013 14:30:26 BST is 0
```

Cronjob : output

```
Number of memexsvr processes at Tue Sep 10 14:59:00 BST 2013 is 3
```

Comment: `(cmd)` works but is a very odd syntax.  The `()` are not necessary, but it feels like you are trying to use `$()` syntax instead of backticks.  Either omit the parenteses or write `x=$(date)`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend being more explicit about how you want to run date. The following page has a good table at the bottom.

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-formatting-dates-for-display/

I think your manual looks something like this:

```
x=`date +"%A, $d %B %Y %r %Z`
```

Answer (score 0):

Cron jobs run with a restricted environment.  `man 5 crontab` for details, or set up a cron job that runs something like `env > cron-env.txt`.

In a (now deleted) comment you said you logged in as super user (i.e., `root`) -- but the `root` account's environment in an interactive shell is likely to differ from the environment set up for a cron job.

The output of the `date` command outside the cron job looks like it's influenced by your locale settings. You probably have something like `$LANG`, `$LC_TIME`, and/or `$LC_ALL` set to some particular value to cause `date` to produce output like `"Tuesday, 10 September 2013 14:30:26 BST"`.

You can either invoke `date` with options to control the output format regardless of the current locale settings, or you can set the appropriate environment variables for the cron job. There are several ways you can do the latter: you can use the `env` command in the `crontab` itself, you can modify your script, or you can set environment variables on a separate line in your `crontab`. Again, `man 5 crontab` for details.

(This is basically what fedorqui's [deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18738974/827263) said, but unfortunately he deleted his answer.)